# Pyspark: devide one row by another in groupBy

Tags: group-by, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, row, aggregate

I have a pyspark data frame and I'd like to divide one row by another within groups. Within groups there will be two rows: one with a count value where `removal == 1` and the other with a count value where `removal == 0`.

How do I divide one count by the other to get the ratio for each group in a new column? The `groupBy` is on `limit` and `test_id`

```python
columns = ['removal', 'limit', 'test_id', 'count']
vals = [
    (1, 'UL', 'AB', 141),
    (0, 'UL', 'AB', 140),
    (1, 'LL', 'AB', 21),
    (0, 'LL', 'AB',12),
    (0, 'UL', 'EF', 200),
    (1, 'UL', 'EF',12)

]
```

What I want: (or in a similar layout)

```python
columns = ['limit', 'test_id', 'ratio', count_1, count_0]
vals = [
    ('UL', 'AB', 1.007, 141, 140)
    ('LL', 'AB', 1.75, 21, 12),
    ('UL', 'EF', 0.06, 12, 200)
]
```

I know ways to do it by splitting and then merging the data again, but I'd rather have a nicer agg function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is only one row per value of `removal`, the straightforward way is to use `where` to filter for each distinct value and `join`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.where("removal = 1").alias("a")\
    .join(df.where("removal = 0").alias("b"), on=["limit", "test_id"])\
    .select(
        "limit",
        "test_id",
        (col("a.count") / col("b.count")).alias("ratio"),
        col("a.count").alias("count_1"),
        col("b.count").alias("count_0")
    ).show()
#+-----+-------+------------------+-------+-------+
#|limit|test_id|             ratio|count_1|count_0|
#+-----+-------+------------------+-------+-------+
#|   UL|     AB|1.0071428571428571|    141|    140|
#|   LL|     AB|              1.75|     21|     12|
#|   UL|     EF|              0.06|     12|    200|
#+-----+-------+------------------+-------+-------+
```